# istringstream from getline return double for last element in line

Tags: c++, file, inputstream

I have a file with some number of chars separated by spaces:

```
# cat file.txt
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
```

I am trying to put them to structure, for example vector, using ifstream and istringstream in followed way:

```
string line;
ifstream file("file.txt");
vector<char> row

while(getline(file, line)){
    char a; 
    istringstream iss(line);
    vector<char> row;
    while(iss){
        iss >> a;
        row.push_back(a);
    }
    table.pushback(row);
}
```

The issue is that iss always return me last element twice in this configuration:

```
for(int i=0; i<table.size(); i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<table[i].size(); j++){
        cout << table[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout <<endl;
}

. . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . 
.
```

I believe that issue is probably caused by end of line character, and for some reasons, last char is stored.

Also when I read numbers line "1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
a program will print "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7"

Is any particular reason why this way of processing file is somehow wrong? Or maybe I am missing something trivial in this example.

Comment: Try `while(iss >> a)`.

Comment: That's help Thanks

Comment: Do you understand why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statement `while(iss)` calls the `bool`-operator on the `istringstream`, which indicates if a failure has occurred in a previous read.
Hence, when the last read has been successful, the loop is entered once more (because no failure has happened so far); the next read of `iss >> a` will then fail, but since you ignore the return value of operation `iss >> a`, the (unchanged) value of `a` will be pushed once more to your vector.

Write `while(iss >> a)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for explanation that was what wasn't intuitive for me